# How could I bring in a simply cell of Excel a value related to the last day of a month, from a PowerPivot DataModel?

Tags: excel, date, powerpivot

I have a Data model in Excel imported with PowerPivot with over 8 million rows and I need to bring in a simple cell the value of the Price corresponding to the last day of the month (or quarter) registered in the base data. For Example:

Power Pivot Data:

| Date | Price |
| --- | --- |
| 26/06/2019 12:00:00 a. m. | 50 |
| 27/06/2019 12:00:00 a. m. | 54 |
| 28/06/2019 12:00:00 a. m. | 58 |
| 01/07/2019 12:00:00 a. m. | 55 |
| 02/07/2019 12:00:00 a. m. | 60 |

I want to be able to look for the date, in my case: "30/06/2019" (or the number of the month), and the returned value would be the price of the last day registered in that month, in this case: "58". Just like a Vlookup function with Approximate match (TRUE) would do.

I've tried with Cube Formulas :

*CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Price].[Date].&["&TEXT(A1;"YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SS")&"]")
*CUBEMEMBER("ThisWorkbookDataModel";"[Measures].[Sum of Price]")
*CUBEVALUE("ThisWorkbookDataModel";B1;B2)

But with this method, I only achieve to bring the price if I use the exact day.

Comment: Can you write a measure in the model or is it read-only for your purposes?

Comment: I can add a measure in the model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write a measure to access the last price and then call that measure in your cube formula. Something like this:

```
LastPrice = 
VAR CurrentDate = SELECTEDVALUE ( Price[Date] )
VAR LastDate = CALCULATE ( MAX ( Price[Date] ), Price[Date] <= CurrentDate )
RETURN
    CALCULATE ( SUM ( Price[Price] ), Price[Date] = LastDate )
```

Comment: Actually you have just given me the idea for a different Data Model, and now I see the best way to use that LastDate formula. Thank You so much, Alexis.